# Difference between "reflection" and "reflexion"

Tags: differences

When is one used instead of the other?

Is there a reason to use one or the other? Or is just two words that can be used without problems?

Comment: -1 and voted to close as general reference, it was in the first dictionary via Google: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=reflexion

Comment: While I undertand that both are the same word with different spellings, I like to think of reflections as contemplations, while reflexions seem more like spontaneous responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Reflexion](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/reflexion)* is used in British English to mean *reflection*. It is seldom used these days.

Answer (score 5):

The same word, two spellings.  Oxford English Dictionary...

> The spelling reflection is now much commoner than reflexion in all uses, probably largely as a result of association with reflect v.; compare also flexion n., connection n., etc. N.E.D. (1905    ) notes that the spelling reflexion was then ‘still common in scientific use, perhaps through its connexion with reflex’.