# One word for the Point of No Return?

Tags: single-word-requests

One word for **Point of No Return**? 
I thought Anti, or Ante was the Ancent Greek one word for it, but I couldn't confirm. Please advise?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Do you remember how many alphabets the word you have in mind had? I'll find it, else it'll bother me for days.

Comment: Similar to (but not the same as) https://english.stackexchange.com/q/371733/9368

Comment: @vickyace - alphabets?  English uses only one.  :-)

Comment: @Jim oops. Guilty.

Comment: 'climax', while not a synonym, can be used to convey the flavor of the tipping point in a story or dramatic turn of events and is a word in common peoples vocabulary.  A word that conveys the excitement and that it is a critical moment might suggest a one way course of action that wouldn't likely be reversed.

Comment: Now I have Kansas playing in my head...

Comment: @Jim : at least that's not against the law.

Comment: There is the similar **go/no go** criteria, which in the case of go-to-orbit reentry calculations literally means no return. See the heading "Example of Go-No-Go Computation" https://history.nasa.gov/SP-45/ch7.htm

Comment: I would say "cliff".

Comment: Single-word requests **must** include an example sentence showing how you want to use your word. The number of answers here is indicative of how inprecise the question is.

Comment: I'm wondering if the "ant-" word you recall reading is "antipodes", a term which does not mean the same as "point of no return", but which might be mistakenly taken to mean that when used in certain contexts.

Answer (score 19):

See **Rubicon**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/rubicon#Rubicon) as

> Point of no return.

But this term isn't that common. You may wanna use *climacteric*, *critical point*, etc. for different situations.

Comment: To elaborate here somewhat, *Rubicon*: the muddy stream that [Julius Caesar crossed with his army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Rubicon), violating Roman law.

Comment: @Nick T: after that event, and on the subsequent sacks of the *eternal city* a general was committed to lay siege on Rome, when crossing the Rubicon. That is actually a great single word for the concept, even better than *zenith* which would have been my first choice

Comment: Nice try, but no. Only had that meaning if you cross or.

Answer (score 4):

**point of no return** is a precise phrase with an arresting meaning: It

> . . . comes from aviation, where it signifies the point where an
>   aircraft does not have enough fuel to return to the starting point.
>   [c. 1940 ] The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary

You might consider crossroad or **crossroads** as a single word--one definition being:

> A point at which a vital decision must be made. ([source - dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crossroad))

Comment: With all due respect, isn't your first suggestion the phrase he wants to replace in the first place.

Comment: @vickyace Yes, it is--I thought it worthwhile to nail down its source. BTW what am I doing wrong in the sources?  I don't want to cause you to need to edit.

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong. Mentioning the source is preferred. It is just better if a **link** to the definition is provided in the answer itself (it helps for quick reference). But of course, you can always roll back on the edit and do it yourself.

Comment: I just visited your answers and saw that you didn't use the link attachment in most of it. FYI, it is the button that looks like a link in the chain, third from left of the screen when you're posting answers.

Answer (score 4):

How about **brink**? From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brink):

1. edge, especially the edge at the top of a steep place
2. a bank, especially of a river
3. the point of onset, e.g.  on the brink of war
4. the threshold of danger

Answer (score 2):

> **event horizon**.
>   NOUN.
>   Astronomy
>   1 A notional boundary around a black hole beyond which no light or other radiation can escape.
>   Example sentences.
>   1.1 A point of no return.
>   *‘we're nearing the event horizon of the presidential election’.*
>   - [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/event_horizon)

Comment: Point of no return - you can't get all the way back. Event horizon - you can't get even part of the way back.

Answer (score 0):

Climax ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climax))

> a: the highest point: culmination *the climax of a distinguished career*
>   b: the point of highest dramatic tension or a major turning point in the action

Comment: But you're implying that there *is* a return.

Answer (score -2):

Would that be, perchance

### ze·nith

ˈzēnəTH/

noun

1. The time at which something is most powerful or successful.
   "*Under Justinian, the Byzantine Empire reached its **zenith** of influence*" **synonyms**: highest point, high point, crowning point, height, top, acme, peak, pinnacle, apex, apogee, crown, crest, summit, climax, culmination, prime, meridian
   "**at the *zenith* of his power**"
2. The point in the sky or celestial sphere directly above an observer.

It is etymologically a [medieval Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=zenith) word:

> ... late 14c., from Old French **cenith** (Modern French **zénith**), from Medieval Latin **cenit, senit,** bungled scribal transliterations of Arabic **samt** "*road, path*,"...

Comment: Once you reach the zenith you're only going to come back down.

Answer (score -2):

It hasn’t entered common usage yet, but in a few years the word you are looking for will be:

> [Brexit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit)

Example of expected usage:

> “I had reached my Brexit, so I made my exit”

[The Memoires of David Cameron, Eton College Press, 2025]

You read it first here.

Comment: As you said, it hasn't entered common usage yet. Also, consider adding a reference/definition and maybe an example of how you would use it.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD — But language is in continual flux — people make things up. Anyway, I've done what you suggested. Perhaps you would like to vote my answer up now and encourage all your friends to do the same.

Comment: @Sushila — not by me or most who use the word. In any case, in retrospect it will certainly be perceived as an event.

Comment: Who's to say there couldn't be a reversal of Brexit?  (Hope springs eternal!)

Comment: @KristinaLopez — If June 8th should see that I will happily withdraw my answer.  Otherwise I doubt I shall live long enough to do so.