# Word for 'Point where you have to start or not finish

Tags: single-word-requests

[Today's comic](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive_print.php?comicid=2019) for [Piled Higher and Deeper (PHd Comics)](http://phdcomics.com/comics.php) posed a question:

> I've reached the point where I have to start writing or I'm not going to finish on time.  The point where...  Hmm, I wonder if there's a name for reaching that point.

So I pose the question for all of you.  Is there a word for reaching that point where, if you don't start now, you'll never be able to finish.

Comment: This seems like related question: [Word for Point of No Return](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384657/one-word-for-the-point-of-no-return)...That said, this question is asking for a word for reaching the point of no return, rather than for the point of no return itself.

Comment: Assuming that the name of the point is *rubicon* (as per the answer to the other question), then what's wrong with *I've reached the rubicon*? In other words, what's wrong with the word *reach* itself?

Comment: Are you looking for the word "threshold"?https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/threshold?q=threshold

Comment: In case anyone hasn't actually followed the link to the comic, you should: it makes this question very "meta".

Comment: What does your research show?

Answer (score 1):

I like Rubicon as a first choice; however, other options might include:
fulcrum, watershed, tipping point, or turning point—although there are nuances to each that might miss your intended meaning, the way I read your question. Another possibility is "I've reached the point where I have to start writing, or the die is cast."

This leads to the luscious (because it feels like velvet rolling off the tongue) French rendition as well: "Les jeux sont faits" as well as—if you'll indulge my nerding out a bit—the Latin expression attributed to Caesar as he crossed the aforementioned Rubicon, "Alea iacta est" or "[Iacta alea est]"[1](https://www.latinitium.com/latinproverbs/iacta-alea-est) depending on preference for emphasis.

Comment: Doesn't your "die" example rather mix cases? Should it be, "I've reached the point where I have to start writing, or the die will be cast"?

Comment: Thank you, James, that is a great question! I considered whether both things were happening simultaneously or as cause-and-effect in progression. What think you? If one has already reached the point, then hasn't the die, in effect, been cast? Tense junkies, anyone?